# Where's the redirect?

Tags: yammer

I'm just getting into using they Yammer api, so please excuse my noobishness. I've registered my app, and I've placed the button from the javascript sdk on a page.  When I click the button it of course logs me in with my yammer credentials yay! But it doesn't re-direct to the page I specified when I registered my app.

Start Page: https://myhost.com/yammer/
Should Re-direct after auto to https://myhost.com/yammer/loggedin.php

Instead the yammer box just goes away, and I stay on the index page. The button changes to "welcome to yammer." If I pop open a 2nd browser tab and type in the re-direct page, that page says I'm logged in. So my question is this. Am I supposed to handle the re-direct myself? It's not really a problem if that's the case, I was just curious. Every piece of documentation I can find indicates that its supposed to do that itself.

Please Advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OAuth 2 to redirect to a specific page,

```
https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[:client_id]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]
```

Or, Using Javascript SDK,

```
yam.getLoginStatus(
  function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      window.navigate("--**Your Redirect Page URL**--");
      }
    else {
      //authResponse = false if the user is not logged in, or is logged in but hasn't authorized your app yet

    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I supposed to handle the re-direct myself?

No. Base on your description, it does not redirect you to the page you specified because you're using the 'Login Button' JSDK. The redirect mechanism kicks in when you're using the [access_token.json](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/test-token) api to login. See a sample code [here](https://github.com/iogbole/yammer_oauthdance/blob/master/app/controllers/oauthdance_controller.rb)